# Struct pointer syntax confusion

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

Hi i'm relatively new to c and was wondering if anyone could explain what exactly i'm doing with the following code.

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct free_list_header {
   u_int32_t magic;  // ought to contain MAGIC_FREE
   vsize_t size;     // # bytes in this block (including header)
   vlink_t next;     // memory[] index of next free block
   vlink_t prev;     // memory[] index of previous free block
} free_header_t;
```

and I'm initialising it within a function using the following...

```
void vlad_init(u_int32_t size)
{

   int sizePow2 = pow(2, ceil(log(size)/log(2)));
   memory = malloc(sizePow2*sizeof(char));
   memory_size = sizePow2;
   strategy = BEST_FIT;

   free_header_t *freeHeader = (free_header_t*)memory;

   freeHeader->magic = MAGIC_FREE;    // the unique value
   freeHeader->size = memory_size;    // amount we malloc'd
   freeHeader->next = 0;              // position of next free block
   freeHeader->prev = 0;              // position of prev free block     
   free_list_ptr = 0;
}
```

my question is what exactly am i doing here and why is it necessary?

```
free_header_t *freeHeader = (free_header_t*)memory;
```

So... i'm declaring a new struct by pointing to it named "freeHeader"? and that is a pointer to it in the memory i have allocated? So this is a way of putting the struct into the malloc'd area to access it out of the function in which im initializing it?

Comment: Is his code you've written, or given to you as part of an assignment or tutorial? Because it feels weird. Like, why initialise the memory using the size of a char, instead of the size of the struct? Why not initialise `freeHeader` directly, instead of first initialising `memory` and then doing the assignment with a cast afterwards?

Comment: Hmmm…your terminology isn't clear, but that may be part of the problem.  What's `sizePow2`?  It had better be at least as big as `memory_size` or you'll (probably) run into problems.  Or maybe the problem is `memory_size`?  Or maybe it's both.

Comment: so its a memory allocator, and the initialing function takes in a number and assigns the smallest power of 2 to malloc at least that much. memory_size ==sizePow2, i'll edit and add the whole function.

Comment: The comment "# bytes in this block (including header)" suggests the memory allocation is supposed to cover both memory for the four members of your struct, plus some free memory for some other purpose, so allocating the size of the struct wouldn't be good, here. The free memory will be a constant offset from the address of the struct itself, so presumably the intention is to access it that way. Presumably this is part of a memory allocator of some sort, although it's using the standard memory allocator to do its work.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malloc returns a void pointer (type void*).  This means it returns a pointer to a memory address and that pointer is not pointing to any specific type. So after the line:

```
memory = malloc(sizePow2*sizeof(char)); //sizePow2 is n bytes to allocate
```

memory is a pointer of type (void *).

```
free_header_t *freeHeader = (free_header_t*)memory;
```

On the left hand side here you are creating a pointer named freeHeader that points to a memory address containing something of type free_header_t
Since you explicitly said this pointer is pointing to an address of type free_header_t to you are casting the other side (currently of type void *) to match it as free_header_t *.

NOTE in C, this works but is not necessary.  The compiler will automatically cast a void * to whatever type you need.  However writing code like this is good practice, in C++ you need to explicitly do this.

Comment: A *cast* is an explicit conversion; a value of type `void*` is implicitly *converted* to any object pointer type. Explicitly casting the result of `malloc` is *not* good practice in C (and using `malloc` at all is not good practice in C++). Casting is necessary if you need to write code that compiles both as C and as C++, but that's a rare requirement.

Comment: Moreover, the declaration of `memory` is not shown in the question, so stating that it "is a pointer of type `void *`" is at best speculation. It could also be of type `free_header_t *`, for all we know.

Comment: @KeithThompson casting malloc is necessary **only** if writing code that compiles on C & C++ ?

Comment: @noob: Pretty much. The cast is unnecessary in C (and can mask certain errors). In C++, you'd normally allocate memory using `new`, not `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
free_header_t * freeHeader = (free_header_t*)memory;
```

you declared a pointer (not an actual struct) to free_header_t struct named freeHeader and you assigned it the value of the pointer named memory. since memory is a pointer to char and yours is a pointer to something else, you used casting.

You currently have only a pointer to an allocated area (of size *sizePow2*sizeof(char)* - note that the size of the struct should be less or equal to the size of the allocated memory).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially equivalent to:

```
free_header_t *freeHeader = malloc(sizePow2 * sizeof(char));
```

It's allocating a block of memory that contains `sizePow2` bytes, and then using that as the address of a `free_list_header` structure.

The reason it uses the `memory` variable is because some other code is going to use the `next` and `prev` members as indexes into that block of memory. As the name implies, this structure just contains the data at the beginning of the memory block, the rest of the memory is managed with other structures.

Answer (score -1):

```
memory = malloc(sizePow2*sizeof(char));
```

You are allocating some memory here. It would be good to just use

```
memory = malloc(sizeof(struct free_list_header));
```

to store an object of the structure.

```
free_header_t *freeHeader = (free_header_t*)memory;
```

Here you are declaring a pointer which would point to memory allocated earlier. You did not technically declare an object of the structure. And you are not putting the structure in to malloc-ed area, you are instead treating the malloc-ed area as an object of the structure.

`free_header_t freeHeader = {0};` would be declaring an object of the structure.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you call `malloc()` function, the operating system returns you a single memory address. When you cast this pointer to a specific type you tell to compiler that every element stored in the memory allocated will consume the size of the specified type and this get the things easier.

Let suppose that you declare a uint64_t* and the size of allocation it's 100 times the size of uint64_t, so you're asking for 800 bytes for the operating system, once the uint64_t takes 8 bytes. If you do not cast this pointer, every time you increase the address with `your_variable++` your program will skip only one byte and you will get in the "middle of the number and will get a weird value", but if you cast your pointer to a uint64_t and increase the address with `your_variable++` your program will skip 8 bytes, going directly to the next number.

In your example, you're telling to the operating system that your pointer will store types of `free_header_t`. You're not obligated to do it, but it is a very good practice.

And yes, if you return this address to another function, the other function can change the value stored in this memory area easily.

Hope it helps!